# MS Graph API: Returns UnknownError

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

```
# Gets the token
token=$(curl -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$appId&client_secret=$clientSecret&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST "https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token" | \
jq -r '.access_token')

# This works: Returns all servicePrincipals
curl -H "authorization: bearer $token" -X GET "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipal"

# This works: one service principal
curl -H "authorization: bearer $token" -X GET "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"

$ This fails: UnknownError - 500 Internal Server Error
curl -H "authorization: bearer $token" -X GET "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/synchronization/jobs"

ERROR:

< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: application/json
< request-id: xxx
< client-request-id: xxx
< x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"South Central US","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"X","ScaleUnit":"XXX","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_XX"}}
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< Date: Tue, 28 Apr 2020 21:52:09 GMT
< Content-Length: 198
< 
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "xxxx",
      "date": "2020-04-28T21:52:09"
    }
  }
* Connection #0 to host graph.microsoft.com left intact
}* Closing connection 0
```

Any suggestion on how to get this to work?

I verified these work from the graph explorer website with my credentials.

This is using a service principal who has global admin permissions.

Comment: Can you share the actual values of client-request-id, request-id and date fields?

Comment: The issue is these endpoints won't work with apps

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/synchronization-synchronizationjob-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http - check under permissions: application - not supported

Comment: If that's the cause of the issue, please post it as an answer.